# Intent in button onclick in getGroupView not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

```
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String MealName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    final String meal = MealName;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.exlist_group,
                null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

    ImageView addM = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addMeal);
    addM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent add = new Intent(v.getContext(), AddProducts.class);
            add.putExtra("MealName", meal);
            v.getContext().startActivity(add);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    item.setText(MealName);
    return convertView;
}
```

Here is xml from group

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:padding="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/addMeal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    />
```

I have helper class "ExpandableListAdapter" with the View getGroupView.
I have button near header's group name and I want to go to another class when I click on this button, but my app stopped when I click on button "add".

Everywhere i have intent:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);       
 startActivity(i);
```

And it working perfectly

i try do the same in ExpandableListAdapterclass

```
 Intent i = new Intent(ExpandableListAdapter.this, AddProducts.class);

            startActivity(i);
```

but "startActivity" is red color <- cannot resolve method startAcivity
And ExpandableListAdapterClass is underlined in red <- cannot resolve constructor Intent

Comment: you need to get the context to start the activity...like context.startActivity(blablaIntent);

Comment: I try. 
            Intent i = new Intent(context,  AddProducts.class);
            context.startActivity(i);

Comment: but still not working

Comment: Any log or error to help us?

Comment: problem solved. I had a problem with AddProducts class - not intent.